# python map function acting on a string of numbers

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I've been playing around with the map function in Python and I was looking for some help in understanding the following behaviour:

```
foo="12345"
print map(int,foo)
```

gives you `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.  Obviously `int(foo)` spits out `12345`.  So what exactly is happening?  Since strings are iterable by character, would the above two lines be synonymous with

```
print [int(x) for x in foo]
```

I know they will output the same result but is there anything different going on behind the scenes?  Is one more efficient or better than another?  Is one more "pythonic"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node81.html#SECTION001152100000000000000

Comment: This falls in the realm of opinion. Opinion: They are functionally similar and it is somewhat user preference. `map` clock a bit faster; List comprehension is more immediately obvious to third party eyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map()` may be somewhat faster than using list comprehension in some cases and in some cases map is slower than list comprehensions.

when using a built-in function:

```
python -mtimeit -s'xs=xrange(1000)' 'map(int,"1234567890")'
10000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s'xs=xrange(1000)' '[int(x) for x in "1234567890"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 20 usec per loop
```

with `lambda`,`map()` becomes slow:

```
python -mtimeit -s'xs=xrange(1000)' '[x*10 for x in "1234567890"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.11 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s'xs=xrange(1000)' 'map(lambda x:x*10,"1234567890")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 usec per loop
```

But, in python 3x `map()` returns a map object, i.e. an iterator

Answer (score 1):

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the
>   results.

From [the documentation for `map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map)

`int()` *attempts* to convert what is passed into an integer and will raise a `ValueError` if you try something silly, like this:

```
>>> int('Hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hello'
```

`map()` will return a list, which has the return value of the function that you ask it to call for any iterable. If your function returns nothing, then you'll get a list of `None`s, like this:

```
>>> def silly(x):
...   pass
...
>>> map(silly,'Hello')
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

It is the short ***and efficient*** way to do something like this:

```
   def verbose_map(some_function,something):
       results = []
       for i in something:
          results.append(some_function(i))
       return results
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` can be thought of to work like this:

```
def map(func, iterable):
    answer = []
    for elem in iterable:
        answer.append(func(elem))
    return answer
```

Basically, it returns a list `L` such that the ith element of `L` is the result of computing `func` on the ith element of your iterable.

So, with `int` and a string of `int`s, in each iteration of the for loop, the element is a specific character, which when given to `int` comes back as an actual `int`. The result of calling `map` on such a string is a list, whose elements correspond to the `int`ed values of the corresponding character in the string.

So yes, if `L = "12345"`, then `map(int, L)` is synonymous with `[int(x) for x in L]`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a huge difference behind the scenes.  If you `print(map)` you'll see it is a builtin.  A builtin function executes faster than one written in python or than most that are based off of how the language is parsed, map uses the fast iter method, a list comprehension does not.  Other that there is no difference.

```
map(int, '1'*1000000)
```

vs.

```
[int(i) for i in '1'*1000000]
```

Using CPython, and the unix time program, map completes in ~3 seconds, the list comprehension in ~5.

Oh, one thing to note, this only pertains when the function passed to map is written in C.

Comment: I was refering to the list comprehension, map calls int repeatedly, so that one exists in both cases, the difference is that the iterable passed to map is passed with the cpython fast loop function, while the other one is parsed by a slower approach.

Comment: Iterating over a string of length 10e7 with [int(i) for i in s] takes ~5 seconds on my machine, map(int, s) takes 3.

Comment: You should clarify your answer then.

Comment: Of course, is that better?  I'm trying to figure out how to explain it better, preferably without dredging around through the C source code.

Comment: You seem to be a little confused. `map` isn't faster in this case because _map_ is a builtin, it's because _int_ is a builtin. The performance gain is so small for recent versions of Python that it's really not worth using `map` for that reason alone

Comment: The code uses int in both cases, the only difference is that one uses map, and the other uses a list comprehension.  Even in versions other than CPython, there is almost certainly going to be a performance difference between the two, though which is faster is uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo="12345"

In [507]: dis.dis('map(int,foo)')
          0 <109>           28769
          3 STORE_SLICE+0  
          4 LOAD_ATTR       29806 (29806)
          7 <44>           
          8 BUILD_TUPLE     28527
         11 STORE_SLICE+1  

def map(func, iterable):
    answer = []
    for elem in iterable:
        answer.append(func(elem))
    return answer

dis.dis('map(int,foo)')
          0 <109>           28769
          3 STORE_SLICE+0  
          4 LOAD_ATTR       29806 (29806)
          7 <44>           
          8 BUILD_TUPLE     28527
         11 STORE_SLICE+1  
dis.dis('[int(x) for x in foo]')
          0 DELETE_NAME     28265 (28265)
          3 LOAD_GLOBAL     30760 (30760)
          6 STORE_SLICE+1  
          7 SLICE+2        
          8 BUILD_TUPLE     29295
         11 SLICE+2        
         12 SETUP_LOOP      26912 (to 26927)
         15 JUMP_FORWARD    26144 (to 26162)
         18 JUMP_IF_FALSE   23919 (to 23940)
```

And timing:

```
In [512]: timeit map(int,foo)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.89 us per loop

In [513]: def mymap(func, iterable):
     ...:     answer = []
     ...:     for elem in iterable:
     ...:         answer.append(func(elem))
     ...:     return answer

In [514]: timeit mymap(int,foo)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.29 us per loop

In [515]: timeit [int(x) for x in foo]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.5 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

"More efficient" is a can of worms. On this computer, it's faster to use map with **CPython**, but the list comprehension is faster for **pypy**

```
$ python -mtimeit 'map(int,"1234567890")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.05 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit '[int(x) for x in "1234567890"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.33 usec per loop
$ pypy -mtimeit 'map(int,"1234567890")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 usec per loop
$ pypy -mtimeit '[int(x) for x in "1234567890"]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.938 usec per loop
```

Python3 shows `map()` to be faster even with the extra call to `list()` that is required

```
$ python3 -mtimeit 'list(map(int,"1234567890"))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.8 usec per loop
$ python3 -mtimeit  '[int(x) for x in "1234567890"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.6 usec per loop
```