# Is there a faster way to get input in python?

Tags: python, performance, input

In coding competitions we encounter inputs like:

```
2 3

4 5
```

So we do the following:

```
m, n = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split(' ')]
```

Is there a faster way of doing the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? Execution time or less code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all practical purposes, That's about as fast as you can get.  On some machines, you may see a speedup on the order or a couple percent if you go with `map` instead of a list comprehension, but that's not guaranteed.

Here's some quick timings on my machine:

```
from itertools import imap
#map
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = map(int,line.split(" "))','from __main__ import line')
4.7857139110565186
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = map(int,line.split())','from __main__ import line')
4.5680718421936035
#list comprehension
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = [int(x) for x in line.split(" ")]','from __main__ import line')
4.3816750049591064
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = [int(x) for x in line.split()]','from __main__ import line')
4.3246541023254395
#itertools.imap
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = imap(int,line.split(" "))','from __main__ import line,imap')
4.431504011154175
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = imap(int,line.split())','from __main__ import line,imap')
4.3257410526275635
#generator expression
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = (int(x) for x in line.split(" "))','from __main__ import line')
4.897794961929321
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = (int(x) for x in line.split())','from __main__ import line')
4.732620000839233
```

Surprisingly, `split()` seems to perform better than `split(" ")`.

---

If you're guaranteed to have ascii input of numbers between 0 and 9, you can do a good bit better using `ord`:

```
>>>timeit.timeit('x,y = [ord(x)-48 for x in line.split(" ")]','from __main__ import line')
1.377655029296875
>>> timeit.timeit('x,y = [ord(x)-48 for x in line.split()]','from __main__ import line')
1.3243558406829834
```

But that imposes a severe restriction on your inputs.

---

One other idea that you could try (I have no idea what the performance implications would be), but you could read your lines from `sys.stdin`:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    x,y = [ord(x)-48 for x in line.split()]
```

Comment: `split()` and `split(" ")` don't actually do the same thing... http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: @JonClements -- I understand that they're not the same.  `split()` and `split(None)` are the same.  However, `split()` is *more general* than `split(" ")` which is why I'm surprised that it is faster (it needs to do test for `"\t"` instead of just `' '`, or runs of `' '` instead of single `' '` for example)

Comment: I'm guessing then that `split()` is probably using something like `strtok(str, " \t")` in C which deals with consecutive delimiters... While, `split(' ')` has to go against that behaviour (and also potentially build a larger result list with `''`s)

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()`, it's faster than list comprehensions when used with built-in functions:

```
m, n = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Comment: @mgilson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702470/python-map-function-acting-on-a-string-of-numbers/12702578#12702578

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this.  I've done the timings myself many times (and gotten conflicting results).  All I'm saying is that the results can vary from machine to machine and that this sort of micro-optimization is unlikely to make any real difference.

Comment: on using map in my submission,execution time reduced from 3.86 to 3.64 seconds